Number of ways to choose two sets with a specific symmetric difference
We consider subsets of $\Omega_N:=\{1,2,\dots,N\}$.
Let $n\in \mathbb N$. How many $(A,B)$ exist such that $A,B\subset \Omega_N$, $|A|>n$, $|B|>n$  and $|A\Delta B|=n$? We denote this set of ordered pairs of sets by $\Theta_n$.
Where $\Delta$ denotes the symmetric difference and $|.|$ the number of elements of a set.
Edit: So far I have tried the following:
\begin{equation}
|\Theta_n|=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{N}{k}\binom{N-k}{n-k}\sum_{l=\max(n-k+1,k+1)}^{N-n}\binom{N-n}{l}
\end{equation}
where I fix $|A\setminus B|=k$ and $|B\setminus A|=n-k$ and then add enough elements $l$ in both sets so that both $|A|$ and $|B|$ are greater than $n$.
Are there any identities that could be of help to simplify this? I am not too familiar with combinatorics.

Please edit to include your efforts.  As a hint:  Fix a set of order $n$ for the symmetric difference and build $A, B$ from that.   Note that any element of $\Omega_N$ must be in $A$ but not $B$, $B$ but not $A$, $A\cap B$ or in neither $A$ nor $B$.

Start with $n=1$ and get an idea of the problem. Assume wlog that $1\in A\Delta B$. This means $1\in A$ or $1\in B$, and every other element of $\Omega_N$ lies in either both $A$ and $B$, or none of them. How many possibilities are there then? Build up on this.

Which “set of sets” do you intend as the meaning of $\Theta_n$? After all, ${(A,B) \in \Omega_n^2 : |A|, |B| > n \mbox{ and } |A \Delta B| =n}$ seen as a relation isn’t transitive.

I am not talking at all about relations. By $\Theta_n$ I just mean the set of all sets that satisfy the requirement.

Another way to enumerate the pairs
$ \left(A , B\right)$ is to choose the set $ D = A {\Delta} B$ first.
There are $ \binom{N}{n}$ choices for $ D$, then we choose
$ A$ such that $ \left|A \cap  D\right| = p  \leqslant  n$
and $ \left|A \setminus  D\right| = q  \leqslant  N-n$. There are $ \binom{n}{p} \binom{N-n}{q}$
choices for $ A$. We must have $ n  <  \left|A\right| = p+q$
and $ n  <  \left|B\right| = \left|A {\Delta} D\right| = n-p+q$. It follows that for
$ 0  \leqslant  n  \leqslant  N$
\begin{equation}\left|{{\Theta}}_{n}\right| = \binom{N}{n} \sum _{p = 0}^{n} \sum _{q = \text{max} \left(p+1 , n+1-p\right)}^{N-n} \binom{n}{p} \binom{N-n}{q}\end{equation}
You could perhaps attempt to simplify this with the help of the incomplete beta function.

@AnneBauval  I updated the answer.

Alright. I am pessimistic, though. Your $\binom Nn\sum\limits_{p<q\atop n-p<q} \binom np\binom{N-n}q$ could also be directly identified with the OP's $\sum\limits_{l>k\atop l>n-k}\binom Nk\binom{N-k}{n-k}\binom{N-n}l$, since $\binom Nk\binom{N-k}{n-k}=\binom Nn\binom nk$.

@AnneBauval Explicit is better than implicit.

I don't understand. Isn't the argument ($\binom Nk\binom{N-k}{n-k}=\binom Nn\binom nk$) explicit?
